# IE 11 Full screen issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var inFullScreen = false; // flag to show when full screen

var fsClass = document.getElementsByClassName("imgFullNormal");
for (var i = 0; i < fsClass.length; i++) {
    fsClass[i].addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
        if (inFullScreen == false) {
            makeFullScreen(evt.target); // open to full screen
        } else {
            reset();
        }
    }, false);
}

function makeFullScreen(divObj) {
    if (divObj.requestFullscreen) {
        divObj.requestFullscreen();
    }
    else if (divObj.msRequestFullscreen) {
        divObj.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
    else if (divObj.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        divObj.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if (divObj.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        divObj.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
    inFullScreen = true;
    return;
}

function reset() {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    }
    else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
    else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    }
    else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
    inFullScreen = false;
    return;
}
```

Using the above code I am able to make both IE and Mozila Firefox full screen. But it turns black, I mean the background.

Basically there is a button on the page. I want show the page on full screen mode by clicking of a button.

Some one please help.

Comment: Could you provide a JsFiddle so we can see the rest of the page.

Comment: dont even know how to do that... JsFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ - copy your code parts in the fields, click run and share